# One line command for getting data from logs

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have apache logs which are updated every minute something like this

Apache.log

```
00:00:01 up 137
00:01:01 up 132
00:02:01 up 137
00:03:01 up 134
00:04:01 up 150
```

I want one line command or a small Unix script that will echo a message whenever the last column value is more than 140 as in the last line and the script still continue to run.

So in short I want a script/command to monitor this log every minute and echo a message if last column value exceeds 140.

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -f log.file | awk '$NF > 140 { print }'
```

Continually monitor the file; when a line has more than 140 in the last column, print it.

That will work for some simpler uses, at any rate.  There are issues that could make it more problematic.  If you send the output of `awk` to file (or anything other than a terminal), you may not get the output written timely.

Comment: `$NF` rather than `$1`

Comment: @pawel7318: yup — thanks.  It was meant to be `$3`, not `$1`, but `$NF` is more accurate anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys for quick answer.

Comment: This log file is created every day.how about if I continually want to monitor it everyday every minute

Comment: You have a multitude of options.  One might be start this process afresh each day, using a `cron` job to stop the previous incarnation and start a new one, shortly after the log file is restarted.  There are probably a myriad others.

Comment: I'll add more details here
-rw-r--r--   1 prod  proc  14944 Jan 11 13:59 20160111
-rw-r--r--   1 proc  proc  08980 Jan 12 13:59 20160112
-rw-r--r--   1 proc  proc  26222 Jan 13 13:59 20160113
-rw-r--r--   1 proc  proc  26616 Jan 14 13:59 20160114

Comment: What does awk $NF do?

Comment: `NF` is the number of fields in the current line; they're numbered `$1…$NF`.  So, `$NF` prints the last field.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use perl like this.

```
$ tailf Apache.log | perl -anle 'if($F[2] > 140){print}'
00:04:01 up 150
```

OR you can also use elasticsearch and process the input data as you like.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to monitor it on regular interval you might use watch command in terminal or add one process in conky application for showing on desktop